# Disabling/enabling all links on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, gallery, disable-link

I'm working on a sales gallery where the user clicks on a image, and a popout box fades in front of the page. The box includes product details, order information, and a stylized exit button to close the box and return to the gallery. The user can also return to the gallery by clicking outside the box. However, when the box is open, I want all links behind the window (nav menu, etc) except the exit button to be disabled. They should be enabled again once the user closes the box. I've tried playing around with things like

```
$('a:not(a.popout)').removeAttr('href');
```

and

`$('a').attr('href', '');`

to no avail. The only thing these manage to do is shut down every link on the page for good and of course there's no way to re-enable them again once I've totally removed the href attribute. Anyone else ever tried to do this? Maybe I'm doing it he hard way. Running out of ideas. Thanks!

Comment: The best wat to handle this is to use modal type popup (overlay),

cheers

Answer (score 1):

When you open the popout, add a `shutdown` class to all anchors:

```
$('a:not(a.popout)').addClass('shutdown');
```

Then just prevent default behavior on such class elements:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.shutdown', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

When you close the popout, remove the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a `$.click()` handler to your links, and `prevent default`:

```
$('a').not('.popout').click( function(event) {
  ...
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('a:not(a.popout)').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

//or 

return false;

})
```